# Access TFS: API or SDK?

Tags: c#, api, tfs, tfs-sdk

What's currently the best way to access an on-premise TFS installation via C#/.NET? Is the SDK still the best option to choose or should all new applications use the TFS API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New applications should use the TFS REST API when possible.  There are [.NET client libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) you can use to access the both the old API and the new API.  From the documentation, note that "REST-based clients only work with Visual Studio Team Services and TFS 2015 (not previous versions of TFS)."